Update XCode project to latest SDK?
I'm working on a C++ project in XCode. It was on SDK version 14.4. A popup appeared, asking me if I want to update XCode to SDK 14.5. I did the update. Now, when I build my project, it fails because it cannot find SDK 14.4. Here is a screenshot of the error: 
Now, when I look in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs, I see MacOSX14.5.sdk, but I no longer see MacOSX14.4.sdk.
I would like help with one of the following:

Idea 1: How can I update my XCode project to use SDK 14.5?
Idea 2: How can I get XCode SDK 14.4 onto my computer again?


install old version xcode and use follow command:
xcode-select -s /path/to/old/xcode

